# Get the access to default java container (TestContainers) in spock test

Tags: java, docker, spock, testcontainers

I have a spock integration test which initiates additional container.

```
@Shared
protected GenericContainer seleniumStandalone =
        new GenericContainer<>("selenium/standalone-chrome:latest")
                .withExposedPorts(4444)
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier({ cmd -> cmd.withName('dockerized-chrome') })
                .withCopyFileToContainer(
                        MountableFile.forClasspathResource("install_python.sh", 0744),"/install_python.sh")
                .withCopyFileToContainer(
                        MountableFile.forClasspathResource("test.py", 0744),"/test.py")
```

Container "dockerized-chrome" has a python script. Script inside him is trying to make a request to endpoint which is originally in java soruce code. That why I am curious that is any way to get information about name or id java container which is created by TestContainers annotation which has also endpoints created in java project.
I added a picture to make it clearer.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, could you rephrase your question to make it clearer. What needs to talk with what? in which way? are you trying to connect ports, or trying to invoke methods on the container interface?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I made the changes. I want to make request inside selenium container using python script to java container created by Testcontainers when my integration test is running.

Comment: If you want to do some browser testing I would recommend to use the great [Geb framework](https://gebish.org/) instead of just using java to spin up a container and then try to hook up a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate between two containers with Testcontainers, make sure to place them within the same network.

You can add a network alias for each container to avoid any IP lookup and port exposure via the host.

The following example is from the Testcontainers documentation and part of the [dedicated section for Advanced Networking](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#advanced-networking):

```
try (
        Network network = Network.newNetwork();

        GenericContainer<?> foo = new GenericContainer<>(TestImages.TINY_IMAGE)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases("foo")
                .withCommand("/bin/sh", "-c", "while true ; do printf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\n\\nyay' | nc -l -p 8080; done");

        GenericContainer<?> bar = new GenericContainer<>(TestImages.TINY_IMAGE)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withCommand("top")
) {
    foo.start();
    bar.start();

    String response = bar.execInContainer("wget", "-O", "-", "http://foo:8080").getStdout();
    assertEquals("received response", "yay", response);
}
```

Use this as a blueprint for your setup and name your Java container e.g. `application`. Next, you can then access this container from within your Selenium container and Python script with `http://application:YOUR_DEFAULT_PORT`.